# How to create sub domain and directory with dot dot. without slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I want to know can we have domain name rewrite into dot dot dot.

I just bought .name domain

Is it possible to rewrite the domain looks as below:

i.call.**your.name**.bla.bla.bla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not how domains works... Your `.name` domain is TLD - [Top Level Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), so basically it's last part separated with dots. Anything else can be after slash (`/`), so you can create:

```
i.call.your.name/bla.bla.bla
```